# How to organize database for translations, performance?

Tags: table, database-design

I am working on a new project for an international website. The task is to get this available in 16 languages.

On the database structure, I was wondering if there is any performance advantage or disadvantage between these two approaches. What would be the preferred choice and why?

**Approach #1**

[image: One line per translated item]

**Approach #2**

[image: One line per language per item]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, it's better practice to encapsulate the data as you did in your **second approach.**

This is because...

> When a fully normalized database structure is extended to allow it to accommodate new types of data, the pre-existing aspects of the database structure can remain largely or entirely unchanged. As a result, applications interacting with the database are minimally affected.

By following this tenant of [normalizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Minimize_redesign_when_extending_the_database_structure), it's far easier to add, update, or remove rows to a table than it is to alter the table by adding/removing columns. Languages may change over time, but the table ideally should stay the same and not need to be in flux to accommodate changes in the data.